# Apache Derby cannot delete records in database because there is no enough time

Tags: derby, squirrel-sql

I guess that records in the table are too big and there is no time for any SQL. I want to delete records from tables and I cannot do it in any way.
What to do?

```
Error: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested, SQL State: 40XL1, Error Code: 30000
```

I am trying using the SQuirrel SQL Client v. 4.0.0. and I cannot.
Delete records, drop table...

Even my spring application cannot do it with this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

No time.

```
Caused By: ERROR 40XL1: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
```

Maybe to manually delete records from a file system but I don't know the path and how to do it.

Comment: Start by trying to figure out why you can't get the lock. Here's some resources to get you started: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DERBY/LockDebugging and https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/devguide/cdevconcepts89097.html

Comment: i guess there is really big CLOB field (by mistake I put a lot of characters there) and now I manage to put derby.locks.waitTimeout = -1, to try even after lock but I started yesterday in 'ij' and it still works. I don't know how to delete records, drop table or anything else. I need to create new schema but I don't want that if it is possible